# madLibs.py Automate the boring stuff

Tags: python, python-re

I am new to python, currently reading 'Automate the Boring Stuff' in Chapter 8 exercise:

> Create a Mad Libs program that reads in text files and lets the user add
> their own text anywhere the word ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB
> appears in the text file.

I have been strugling with the replacement part in my code, and now i'm getting this error:

> newText = REGEX.sub(i, replaceItem, textContent)
> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
import re

textFile = open('C:\\Users\\Cris\\madLibStory.txt')
textContent = textFile.read()
#fileName = os.path.basename('C:\\Users\\Cris\\madLibStory.txt')
textFile.close()

REGEX = re.compile(r'(ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB)')
matches = REGEX.findall(textContent)
print(matches)

for i in matches:
    replaceItem = input('Insert substitute for %s: ' %i)
    newText = REGEX.sub(i, replaceItem, textContent)

print(newText)
file = open('C:\\Users\\Cris\\madLibStoryLIBED.txt', 'w')
file.write(newText)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter to [`Pattern.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub) is an int type called `count`.

Perhaps you wanted to use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) rather than `REGEX.sub()`, which does accept three string parameters before the optional args.

Comment: Thank you so much! is such an obvious mistake.